# Ethernet to RCA

Tags: ethernet, transfer-function, video, rca

I'm trying to get a few cameras (RCA) to connect to a multiplexer and then display their feeds on a monitor, but with one of those cameras connected to my computer instead. I ran into a bit of a problem/not-sure-of-something moment.

I'm using four cameras, so there's this [balun](https://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/852270-REG/MuxLab_500032_Quad_Video_Balun_with.html/overview) that lets me input four video signals and send them using a single UTP cable.

My question is: How do I go from Ethernet back to four RCA cables again? I tried to find a product online, but failed.

Comment: Did you read the product page what it is compatible with?

Answer (score 4):

This is a passive adapter that converts the single ended coaxial video signal to a balanced differential signal suitable for transmission over twisted pairs - the kind of twisted pairs that are readily available as Ethernet cables. The key words on the listing are “balun” (for balanced to unbalanced) and “passive”.

To convert the signal back you would use a duplicate balun at the other end.

Unfortunately at no point is this “Ethernet” or compatible at all with modern networking hardware and software - it just changes the cable type.

To learn more about how baluns work and why they’re used, consider this Wikipedia article:

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Balun